# Write lines in file when the file exists c#

Tags: c#, file

i try to write line in file when this exists:

My code is next:

```cs
string strRuta = "C:\File.txt"

if (!Directory.Exists(strRuta))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strRuta);


string psContenido = "Hola";

if (!(File.Exists(strRuta + strNombreArchivo)))
{
    swArchivo = File.CreateText(strRuta + strNombreArchivo);
}


if (!psContenido.ToLower().Contains("error"))
{
    swArchivo.WriteLine(psContenido);

    swArchivo.Flush();
    swArchivo.Close();
    swArchivo.Dispose();
    File.SetCreationTime(strRuta + strNombreArchivo, DateTime.Now);
}
```

but when run this program i have a error in WriteLine, i don´t undertand which is the reason, could you help me?

I would like to know how to write in the file(in the next line the word)

Comment: I could duplicate-close this for the common NullReferenceException you are obviously getting, but that's not the most important point here. Everything before `if (!psContenido...` could be just `swArchivo = File.AppendText(strRuta + strNombreArchivo)` (or even better, using `Path.Combine`), why you ask? Because `File.AppendText` "Creates a StreamWriter that appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist." according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Just pointing out that writing to the root c: directory in modern versions of windows is at best discouraged, and at worst prohibited. Write to C:\temp\File.txt instead.

Comment: *I have a error* is not a useful problem description unless you also tell us **what** error you have. There's an error message that comes with that error, and it's right on the screen in front of you. Unfortunately, we cannot see your screen, so you need to give us that information in your question. It makes it much easier to help you fix an error when we know what the error is, and you have that information right in front of you.

Comment: You can replace all that `CreateText`, `WriteLine`, `Flush`, `Close`, and `Dispose` code with: `File.AppendAllText(strRuta + strNombreArchivo, psContenido + "\n");` The `AppendAllText` method will create the file if it doesn't exist, and then append the text to the end of the file, and then close it. Look into the [`File` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) - it has a bunch of very helpful methods for dealing with files that handle all the stream reader/writer stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems, I think. First, you're specifying what looks like a file name and creating a directory with that name (not sure if this is intentional or not). Second, you can use the static helper method `AppendAllText` of the [`File` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) to both create the file if it doesn't exist, and to write the contents to the end of the file. It handles all the streamwriter stuff for you, so you don't have to worry about calling close and dispose.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string directory = @"C:\private\temp";
    string fileName = "MyFile.txt";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
    string fileContents = "This will be written to the end of the file\r\n";

    // This will create the directory if it doesn't exist
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    // This will create the file if it doesn't exist, and then write the text at the end.
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, fileContents);

    File.SetCreationTime(filePath, DateTime.Now);
}
```